# Python 3 + Flask application that uses routes, views and GET parameters

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have the following problem for part of my python class homework:

Using the functions you created earlier, make a flask application that takes arguments and displays the results of the calculations using routes/views.

For example, you will have three routes and they can be called square, triangle, and cost. You will pass GET query string parameters to these routes and the view will display the appropriate results.

I did some research and could not figure out what to do with Flask. My teacher gave a very short overview in class on Flask, and I'm a beginner with Python, so hoping someone can help me.

I just have no idea what to do. Any help I can get would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code for the functions (this code works)

functions.py file:

```
# Using the input function ask the user for the base of a triangle and store in a variable
print()
b = int(input(str(user_name)+ ", please enter the base length of your triangle: "))
print()

#Using the input function ask the user for the height of a triangle and store the value in a variable
#Where b = length of base and h = length of height
h = int(input("Now please enter the height length of your triangle: "))
print()

#Call your function passing the two variables that contain the values for base and height
print("The area of your triangle", user_name, "is", str(area_tr(b,h)) +".")
print()


#Part 3: Total Cost
#Assume you work for an outdoor clothing company. Your job is to find out the total cost of buying raw materials for a winter jacket.
#Create a function that takes two arguments and returns the total cost using the formula:
#Total cost = Number of units X price per unit
def tc_wjacket(u,p):
    """
    total cost of buying raw materials for a winter jacket.
    Total cost = Number of units X price per unit.
    """
    return u * p

#Using the input function ask the user for the numbers of units and store it in a variable.
print()
u = int(input(str(user_name)+ ", please enter the number of winter jackets you want for your store: "))
print()
#Using the input function ask the user for the price per unit
p = int(input("Now please enter the cost of the raw materials per jacket: "))
print()
#Call your function passing the two variables that contain the values for number of units and price per unit
print(str(user_name)+ ", according to my calculations, the cost to buy the raw materials for", b ,"jackets with at", p ,"dollars per jacket is", tc_wjacket(u,p) ,"dollars.")
print()
print("I hope this information was helpful " + str(user_name)+ ".")
print()
```

Comment: This website is not a homework solving website. If you want you can hire people online to help you.  If you have a specific question feel free to ask. Also none of your code appears to use flask. Is there something you didn't add to the question?

Comment: I figured it out. Perhaps this answer will help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
#importing Flask
from flask import Flask

#creating an app instance in the current namespace
app = Flask(__name__)

#decorator
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/square/<int:side1>/<int:side2>/<int:side3>/<int:side4>")

def add(side1,side2,side3,side4):
    """
    perimeter of a square
    """
    perim = (side1 + side2 + side3 + side4)
    return "<h2>Your square's parimeter is {}</h2>".format(perim)

@app.route("/triangle/<int:b>/<int:h>")

def area_tr(b,h):
    """
    Function calculates the area of a triangle
    formula = (base * height)/2
    """
    area_tr = b * h / 2
    return "<h2>Your triangle's area is {}</h2>".format(area_tr)

@app.route("/cost/<int:u>/<int:p>")


def tc_wjacket(u,p):
    """
    total cost of buying raw materials for a winter jacket.
    Total cost = Number of units X price per unit.
    """
    total_cost = u * p
    return "<h2>Your triangle's area is {}</h2>".format(total_cost)


#debug=True allows us to make changes to our code and see them in the browser without having to re-run our app
app.run(debug=True, port=8000, host='0.0.0.0')
```